# MySQL save table output from stored procedure to table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to use table output of stored procedure outside of it.
Stored procedure produces pivot table which means:

- I don't know exact structure of output table - cannot use INSERT INTO for permanent / temporary table (they expect exact table structure).
- Complex SQL statements inside (not only SELECT statements) - cannot export SQL code outside of stored procedure in some SELECT.

How to use SP table output meaning these conditions?

Comment: I am having hard time understanding your question. Can you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in non-fixed structure of SP output.

So, CREATE TABLE flds / INSERT INTO not working when table structure not exactly defined before.
But exists very flexible syntax for CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE AS which is not require exactly defined table structure. It helped me.

Hope this will help to MYSQL beginners.